# mt.exe in Qt StandAlone .exe

Tags: qt, exe, mt

I finally built a static version of Qt 5.1.1 using microsoft visual studio. I created my .exe standalone file using this code:

```
qmake Hello.pro
nmake release
cd release
mt.exe -manifest Hello.exe.manifest -outputresource: Hello.exe;1
```

what is mt.exe and what does the last line do with the "Hello.exe" file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `CONFIG += embed_manifest_exe` though, but in essence you need to put the manifest file beside your executable and the last line seems to take care of that.

That is, it is adding a manifest to your "Hello.exe" executable file.

If you do not happen to know what manifest files are, then you can read the MSDN documentation below, but in short: they are carrying run time information for your executable in this particular case:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx